# World territorial units for statistics

Tags: data, statistics

My current assignment required to do research and produce world territorial units for statistics.

In Europe it was easy thanks to [Eurostat](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/nuts_nomenclature/introduction). Even non-commercial GIS data is available [here](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/popups/references/administrative_units_statistical_units_1). Now outside Europe I am completely lost. I know there are some [regional organizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regional_organizations_by_population) that exist. What I don't know is how they organize their territorial units for the member countries.

Any ideas?

Comment: what statistics are you after?

Comment: I am interested in economic and population.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at http://www.gadm.org/  GADM ia a database of Global Administrative Areas

Comment: Thanks for mentioning gadm project but again i am looking for for some subdivision info based on some statistics. I have in house really good coverage of postal and admin layers of whole world. As Eurostat has make my life easy by producing NUTS layers which are basically based on the admin layers of different countries in Europe. So I am looking for same information for whole world.